# Android - Passing an Url by a Text Filed

Tags: java, android, http, url, request

I'm trying to pass an url by a field text to make a HttpPost but i'm getting this error:

```
Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText%7B1647e90+VFED..CL.+......I.+0%2C0-0%2C0+%237f0d00ad+app%3Aid%2Ffield_url%7D
```

Here is my Code

-Service

```
class ThreadInBackgroud extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        try{

            Log.i("LOG", "LocationService.doInBackground()");
            HttpConnection.getSetDataWeb(URLEncoder.encode(Settings_Fragment.url,"UTF-8"),
                    "send-map-coords",
                    mMessageEB);
            stopSelf();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("LOG", e.getMessage(),e);
        }

    }
}
```

-Fragment

```
Button saveButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            SharedPreferences.Editor editorUrl = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("url_key", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editorUrl.putString("url_key", url_field.getText().toString());
            editorUrl.commit();

        }
    });

    url = url_field.toString();
```

-HttpConnection

```
 public static String getSetDataWeb(String url, String method, MessageEB m) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8"));
```

I'd like to pass the url as a variable, so that the user could change the url through a text field

Comment: And i dont know if using Shared preferences is the best way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
url = url_field.toString();
```

to

```
url = url_field.getText().toString();
```

because need to call `getText()` method to get text from input field otherwise call of `toString()` method on View object will give `string representation of it`

Comment: Hey. With this modification i was able to get the string stored in the text field. But i'm still geting the same error with the path. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=http://www.myurl.com/package/pack/pack.php

Comment: @ClaudioCastro: just use `HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
url = url_field.toString();
```

to

```
url = url_field.getText().toString();
```

and make url public so that you can access in another service

```
public String url;
```

Comment: Hey. With this modification i was able to get the string stored in the text field. But i'm still geting the same error with the path. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=myurl.com/package/pack/pack.php

Answer (score 0):

You should not encode the entire URL, since that will result in some garbage like

```
(http%3A%2F%2F23.23.82.251%3A9116%2Fsolr%2Fdb%2Fselect%3Fq%3D*%3A*%2B_val_%3A%2522geodist%2528%2529%2522%26fq%3D(ProviderType%3A10)%26rows%3D100%26wt%3Djson%26indent%3Dtrue%26fl%3DProviderID%2CProviderType%2CProviderName%2CProviderAddress%2CCityAreaID%2CCityAreaName%2CCity%2CState%2CLatlong%2Cscore%26fq%3D{!geofilt}%26sfield%3DLatlong%26pt%3D20.296059%2C85.82454%26d%3D5%26sort%3Dgeodist()%2520asc)
```

This will fail because it cannot be parsed as a normal HTTP URL.

Instead try using

HttpPost httpPost= new HttpPost("http://YOUR URL/...");